# Declare all my images with a javascript array

Tags: javascript

I want to declare all of my images using their sources, but not to have to declare each image individually on their own lines.

Instead of doing this for each image:

```
var Image1 = new Image();
Image1.src = "Image1.png";
var Image2 = new Image();
Imag2e.src = "Image2.png";
```

I'm doing this:

```
var tab1image = new Array("Image1" , "Image2"  );
var tab2image = new Array("Image1.png" , "Image2.png" );

for (var i=0; i<tab1image.length; i++)
{
 var tab1image[i] = new Image();
 tab1image[i].src = tab2image[i];
}
```

But I have this error :
 **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You try to declare a variable with an invalid name: `var tab1image[i] = new Image();`

Comment: Just to exapnde on DaCurse's comment, you dont need to redeclare the variable. tab1image[i] = new Image(); is enough

Comment: Whilst I your approach isn't one I'd take, the problem is that you have a typo. See @DaCurse's comment

Answer (score 0):

`var tab1image[i]` isn't valid.

`tab1image[i]` is referring to `tab1image` which is a value that exists, so you don't need the var on that line. You're setting a property of the existing `tab1image` variable, not declaring a new one.

However, if you'd like to convert an array of sources to an array of images, you can use the map function of an array to do that:

```js
var imageSources = ["Image1.png" , "Image2.png"];

var images = imageSources.map(source => {
   var image = new Image();
   image.src = source;
   return image;
});

// images is now an array of images, just like the tab1image array in your original code
```

That way you don't need to create a seperate array to hold the images ahead of time!